# Bootstrap Typeahead And TagsInput

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm work on Bootstrap Typeahead. And I'm using bootstrap 3.1, and download this script. http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/

And I'm using also http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/bootstrap3/

```
<input id="Subject" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject">
```

And my script is;

```
$('#Subject').tagsinput({
typeahead: {
    source: ['Amsterdam', 'Washington', 'Sydney', 'Beijing', 'Cairo']
}
});
```

tagsinput plugin is working but, typeahead isn't work. How can i solve this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#Subject').tagsinput({
    //options for tagsinput here
}).typeahead({
    source: ['Amsterdam', 'Washington', 'Sydney', 'Beijing', 'Cairo']
});
```

The `typeahead()` and `tagsinput()` methods are not necessarily related, so you need to call them both separately on your selector (via [method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining)).

Comment: `TypeError: $(...).tagsinput(...).typeahead is not a function`

Comment: @YannBertrand: Same here. Any suggestions?